# How not to automatically build last version on visual studio when you have a compile error?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

So, don't know what else to describe, but when I have any compile error and press F5, my visual studio automatically builds the last successfull version, and I would like to at least ask me first if I do wanna do that.

Answer (score 0):

From this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925125/visual-studio-re-enable-build-failed-run-last-success-dialogue-box

The process is as follows for `Visual Studio 2010` and above (but should be similar for previous versions):

- On the menubar go to: `'Tools' --> 'Options'`
- Go to `'Project and Solutions' --> 'Build and Run'`
- There you can find a combobox under the label `'On run, when build or deployment errors occur...'`. Select an appropriate option.